# How do I iterate through keyframes in an animation clip?

Tags: unity, animation

I have an animation clip that animates a complex model.

I would like to ask if it is possible to iterate through all bones and their key frames like that:

(pseudo code)

```
 foreach( GameObject obj in objects)
 {
     //get animation
     Animation anim = obj.GetComponent<Animation>();
     
     //some how get the keyframes
     Keyframes[] keys = anim.???
 
     Vector3 trans = keys[0].transform.localPosition;
     Quaternion rot = keys[0].transform.localRotation;
 }
```

I have copied this question from [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/305893/get-keyframes-from-animation.html) because it resembles just the very same question but didn't yield an answer.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the functionality provided by the [AnimationUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationUtility.html) class?

Comment: @DMGregory No, I am currently stuck at the fact that animationclip.events.Length is always 0. So it doesn't seem to be possible to access the animation clip events directly, and that is why you pointed me to the AnimationUtility class?

Comment: Your question does not ask about animation events. Is that what you want, instead of float curves like position x/y/z? This question also looks quite related to [your previous one.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/193984/39518) Would you like users to focus on giving you answers to that one instead?

Comment: I don't think that I actually mean "events". The only thing that I could get from an AnimationClip were the ".events", so I thought these would be the keyframes that I'm after.

Comment: They are not, as the documentation shows. AnimationEvents are callbacks where the animation invokes a function in your script when it reaches a particular frame. The AnimationUtility class gives you methods to get the float curves of an animation and iterate over/adjust its keyframes.

Comment: I thought 'Animation' type was the legacy system. I thought it was Animator and AnimationClip in the Mecanim system. Since you specified it was human character, I think it's better to use Mecanim so you can use the IKTargets etc from the 'Human Animation Retargeting' . (I might be wrong, sorry if I am)

Comment: @I_Keep_Trying No, I don't use Humanoid rig. I use a Generic rig.

Comment: By saying that it's human I just wanted to say that it's not a simple ball bouncing animation but a huge animation clip monster with many bones.

Comment: Ah ok fair enough. I simply happened to notice it and recently I made a human character without Mecanim and I regretted it because I wasnt able to use the cool features like IK targetting to have hands holding items etc etc (of course I am sure you could create this in code yourself, without Mecanim, if you are clever)